# How do I change the background on a webform using asp.net razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

yes, I know this is basic, but how do I change the background colour of my razor web application from razor? Also, how would I change text colour in the web application too? If this has already been asked and answered before, I apologise. Please link that QA to me so I and future confused programmers will know where to look. Please forgive me for my stupidity. Here is the code:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>~Web APP to C# Form~</p>
</div>
<!--<form method="post">
    <label>First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br />
    <label>Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br />
    <label>Email Address: </label>
    <input type="email" name="emailAddress">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
    -->

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

<form asp-controller="Index" method="post">
    Enter Ticket Number:
    @Html.TextBox("ticketnumber")
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <br />
    ----------------------------------------------------
    <br />
    Ticket Title:
    @Model.ticketTitle
    <br />
    <br />
    Ticket Description:
    @Model.ticketDescription
</form>
```

Comment: You need to learn about css style sheets and bootstrap.

Comment: What about just telling me how to change the background colour? (eg; make a comment including code that would tell me what to input into the page file)

Comment: The background color of entire page can be changed by changing style of body tag. In your code I don't see body tag, I might be there in layout page if you are using any. The body tag should be `<body style="background-color:green">`. I hope this help you.

Comment: This was it. Thanks for the answer, Chetan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body style="background-color:green">
```

Answer solved by Chetan Ranpariya.